# CSS Responsive Mobile Issue - Foundation Front-end framework ( ZURB)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

My website uses a Foundation Front-end framework for my website, so it's a responsive design for mobile devices.

I have an issue, with how the data is displayed on my website when used on a mobile.

I would like the sidebar widget contents on my website to display above the items (health clubs) on the mobile version of the website. See my sidebar widget has a filter section, So I really need that displayed before the (health clubs).

**Question:** What do I need to change to display the sidebar widget on top? Apologises I'm ok at CSS but this is pretty advanced for my skill level.

**Here is the website: (PC version)** 
http://s10.postimg.org/cl1n43w95/website.png

Here is how the website is displayed on the mobile. Note How my items are all above the sidebar. I'd like the sidebar widget above the items:

http://s27.postimg.org/8adw402gz/screenshot2_sidebarunder_items.png

**Here is the foundation code I believe I need to change:**

```
/* #Foundation Style
================================================== */
.row .column, .row .columns{ -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box;        box-sizing: border-box; }

.container{ margin: 0px auto; max-width: 960px; padding: 0px 20px; }
.container.wrapper{ margin: 0px auto; max-width: 1000px; padding: 0px; }

.row { width: 1140px; max-width: 100%; min-width: 727px; margin: 0 auto; }
.row .row { width: auto; max-width: none; min-width: 0; margin: 0 -10px; }

.column, .columns { float: left; min-height: 1px; padding: 0 10px; position: relative;        margin-bottom: -12px; }

.row .one { width: 8.333%; }
.row .two { width: 16.667%; }
.row .three { width: 25%; }
.row .four { width: 33.333%; }
.row .five { width: 41.667%; }
.row .six { width: 50%; }
.row .seven { width: 58.333%; }
.row .eight { width: 66.667%; }
.row .nine { width: 75%; }
.row .ten { width: 83.333%; }
.row .eleven { width: 91.667%; }
.row .twelve { width: 100%; }

.row .one-fifth{ width: 20%; }
.row .one-sixth{ width: 16.667; }

img{ max-width: 100%; height: auto; }
img { -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; }
object, embed { max-width: 100%; }

/* #Foundation Mobile Size
================================================== */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    body { -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
        width: 100%; min-width: 0; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0; padding-left: 0;     padding-right: 0; }

.container{ margin: 0px auto; max-width: 420px; }
.container.wrapper{ margin: 0px auto; max-width: 460px; padding: 0px; }

.row { width: auto; min-width: 0; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0; }

.row .column, .row .columns { width: 100%; float: none; }

.column:last-child, .columns:last-child { float: none; }
[class*="column"] + [class*="column"]:last-child { float: none; }

.column:before, .columns:before, .column:after, .columns:after { content: ""; display:         table; }
.column:after, .columns:after { clear: both; }
}

/* #Custom Style
================================================== */

/*--- header area ---*/
.header-wrapper .responsive-menu-wrapper{ display: none; }

/* #Custom Mobile size
================================================== */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
/*--- header area ---*/
.header-wrapper .logo-wrapper{ float: none; }
.header-wrapper .navigation-wrapper{ display: none; }
.header-wrapper .responsive-menu-wrapper{ display: block; }     
.header-wrapper .top-search-form{ display: none; }

div.logo-right-text{ float: none !important; text-align: center !important; 
    padding-top: 0px !important; padding-bottom: 20px; }

div.feedback-wrapper{ display: none; }

div.top-navigation-left, div.top-navigation-right{ text-align: center; float: none; }
div.social-wrapper { float: none; display: inline-block; margin-top: 5px; }

/*--- single page ---*/
div.single-portfolio .port-media-wrapper { max-width: 100%; width: 100%; float: none;     margin-bottom: 20px; }
div.single-portfolio .port-content-wrapper { overflow: visible; }
div.single-portfolio .port-nav .port-prev-nav, div.single-portfolio .port-nav .port-next-    nav { margin-bottom: 15px; }

/*--- page item ---*/
div.gdl-blog-medium .blog-media-wrapper { margin-right: 0px; width: 100%; }
div.gdl-blog-medium .blog-context-wrapper { overflow: visible; }
div.price-item{ margin-bottom: 20px; }

div.column-service-row{ border-left-width: 0px; }

/*--- shortcode ---*/
.shortcode1-4, .shortcode1-4.last, 
.shortcode1-3, .shortcode1-3.last, 
.shortcode1-2, .shortcode1-2.last,
.shortcode2-3, .shortcode2-3.last, 
.shortcode3-4, .shortcode3-4.last,
.shortcode1-5, .shortcode1-5.last, 
.shortcode2-5, .shortcode2-5.last,
.shortcode3-5, .shortcode3-5.last, 
.shortcode4-5, .shortcode4-5.last{ width: 100%; }

/*--- slider ---*/
.flex-caption{ display: none !important; }
.nivo-caption{ display: none !important; }
.anythingSlider{ display: none !important; }

/*--- footer ---*/
div.copyright-left, div.copyright-right{ float: none; text-align: center; }
}
```

Thanks Guys, Sorry if i'm not very clear.

Comment: Sorry if i am not clear. Im not sure where to look in terms of code for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

With the foundation grid you can change the order of columns, which is probably what you are looking for.

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html

Look for "Source Ordering"

That should guide you on the right path. Otherwise it would be helpful if you post the relevant markup.

#### second attempt

If you look at the source of your second page http://goo.gl/ijZ1JF you find three elements:

```
<div class="row single page"> ...

<div class="eight column columnopaddingright"> ...

<div class="four column  columnopaddingleft"> ...
```

Do you get the desired result if you modify them for testing purpose like this?

```
<div class="row single page" style="display: table;">

<div class="eight column columnopaddingright" style="display: table-footer-group;">

<div class="four column  columnopaddingleft" style="display: table-header-group;">
```

Comment: Thanks a million!! I'm actually trying to find references to Source Ordering in the code. See I'm using a website template so I'm finding it tricky.

Comment: Im using wordpress, this is very confusing

Comment: I have a link to my website. http://goo.gl/bQ3DCF if that's useful. The template is purchase only but if you are on dropbox or google drive id be happy to send you on a copy for review. thanks

Comment: I see, forget about my answer. Your template is not using the foundation framework. I missunderstood your question in the first place.

Comment: Sorry about that Jens W. Thanks for taking the time to help out really appreciate that.

Comment: Hi, I added the above code to category.php, I'm kind of confused what to do next sorry.

Comment: The site should now behave in the desired way. For small browser size the sidebar is above the result. I will extend my answer tomorrow.